# How to prove that the product of a decreasing monotonic function and a strictly increasing monotonic function is a concave function?

Tags: calculus, functions, convex-analysis

Given that I have a strictly increasing monotonic function $f$ and a decreasing monotonic function $g$, are there any nice properties to show that the product function $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$ is a concave function for $0 \leq x \leq 1$?

I think the standard way is to proof that $h''(x) \leq 0$, for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, but I am wondering if there is another way to proof it.

Comment: Is it true? Consider segment $[0,1]$ and functions $f(x) = x+1$, $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ ...

Comment: @Oleg567 It is possible. Consider segment [0,1], and functions $f(x) = x, g(x) = e^{-x/5}$

Comment: Yes, there exists examples, and there exists counterexamples of this statement. I said that it is not true for all pairs of increasing (on $[0,1]$) functions $f,g$ .

Answer (score 1):

There are always many ways to prove a statement. However the most simple (and elegant) one will be using the chain rule:
$$h''(x) = (fg)''(x) = (f'g + fg')'(x) = f''g(x) + 2f'g'(x) + fg''(x)$$
Here you see you'll also need some restrictions to $f'', g''$ as well as $f,g$ for the proof to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally wrong if there are no other restrictions for your functions, e.g.
when $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ and $g(x)=e^{-x},$  then 
$f$ is strictly increasing monotonic, $g$ is decreasing monotonic, but 
$h(x)$ is **strictly convex** on $(0,1)$:
$$h''(x) = 2 e^{x^2-x}+(2x-1)^2 e^{x^2-x} > 0$$

Comment: Ok so can we say that the product will be quasiconcave?